# What is this Problem in React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React Project and I am having an error,
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZpzz.png)

But When I print that same Property inside of component, it doesn;t give me that error.

> GroupPage.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'
import { history } from '../../routers/client/AppRouter'

const GroupPage = ({ id }) => {

    const [details, setDetails] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('project-some'))
            const headers = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }

            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/get/group', { id }, { headers })
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setDetails(res.data)
                return
            }

            console.log(res.status)
        })()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
                console.log(details.admin)
            }
            <h1>{details.name}</h1>
            <p>Description: {details.description}</p>
            {/* <h4>Admin : {details.admin.userName}</h4> */}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    return {
        id: history.location.state.id
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupPage)
```

So, in above file If I uncomment the `<h4>` tag then I will get the error.
But the `console.log(details.admin)` is giving me desired output in console.

What's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the initial rendering `details` will be an empty object (`{}`). Therefore, `details.admin` will be `undefined` which result in above error you mentioned.

Use it with optional chaining

```
<h4>Admin : {details.admin?.userName}</h4>
```

Or you can have the initial state as follows.

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState({
  admin: {
    userName: "", // you can keep null as well
  },
});
```

Or you can use conditional rendering as well as follows.

```
{details.description && <p>Description: {details.description}</p>}
{details.admin?.userName && <h4>Admin : {details.admin.userName}</h4>}
```

Comment: I like this Optional chaining option more ! Thanks !

Comment: nice...happy coding..!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access variables that do not exist. The return statement is trying to show the username of the admin before it is set by the api request. You can have an && condition to wait for this value to not be 'falsey' (having null-like values), or you can provide default values beforehand like so:

OPT1:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'
import { history } from '../../routers/client/AppRouter'

const GroupPage = ({ id }) => {

    const [details, setDetails] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('project-some'))
            const headers = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }

            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/get/group', { id }, { headers })
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setDetails(res.data)
                return
            }

            console.log(res.status)
        })()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
                details && console.log(details.admin)
            }
            <h1>{details && details.name}</h1>
            <p>Description: {details && details.description}</p>
            {/* <h4>Admin : {details && details.admin.userName}</h4> */}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    return {
        id: history.location.state.id
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupPage)
```

OPT 2:

```
let defaultVals = {
  description:"",
  name:"",
  admin:{
    username:""
    }
  }
  
const [details, setDetails] = useState(defaultVals)
```

Comment: oops, that was a silly mistake! I guess !
thanks a lot for your help I would like to go with Option 1 !

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)